# How to resolve merge conflict in xib file with Xcode 10

Tags: ios, git, version-control, xcode10

I am using Xcode 10 to merge two branches. I'm get conflict in .xib file.

Unfortunately Xcode 10 not showing any changes with highlight and proper position of conflicts:

[image]

but in .swift file it work fine and show changes with highlight:

[image]

Comment: it is difficult to fix storyboard / xml file conflicts I suggest you to ignore one person change and manually do it

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Thanks, and i kow how to resolve it but Xcode not showing proper position of conflicts

Comment: There aren't conflicts in the xib?

Comment: @Kerberos conflicts is there.

Comment: Due it could be a bit tricky I always merge and ignore my changes (conflicting ones) on the storyboard and I use two instances of Xcode, one with my stuff and one with the merged code (without the conflicting files), and manually add my stuff into the storyboard.